# Having trouble with the file path on open() function in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, encoding, pickle

I'm trying to load a pickle file on my machine learning API, but I keep getting path errors.

`model = pickle.load(open(scaler_filepath, 'rb'))`

but then for some reason I get an error that the file is not found: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '..\\..\\models\\lr_scaler.pkl'

this is how I'm loading the pickle files:

```
model_path = os.path.join(os.path.pardir,os.path.pardir,'models')

scaler_filepath = os.path.join(model_path, 'lr_scaler.pkl')

model_filepath = os.path.join(model_path, 'lr_model.pkl')

scaler = pickle.load(open(scaler_filepath, 'rb'))

model = pickle.load(open(model_filepath, 'rb'))
```

this gives me the FileNotFoundError. setting the paths as raw strings didn't work either, but what's insteresting is that if I print to check the paths:

```
print(model_filepath)

print(os.path.getsize(scaler_filepath))
```

it returns the correct path and the file size:

..\..\models\lr_model.pkl

1227

so it appears like the paths are correct but for some reason they don't work when I open them inside pickle.load()

even using raw strings

```
scaler = pickle.load(open(r'..\..\models\lr_scaler.pkl', 'rb'))

model = pickle.load(open(r'..\..\models\lr_model.pkl', 'rb'))
```

I still get: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '..\\..\\models\\lr_scaler.pkl'

and switching the \ to / didn't work either. don't know what else to do :(

edit:
if I check the paths with `print(os.path.exists(model_filepath))`, this happens:

```
True 
True 
* Serving Flask app "machine_learning_api" (lazy loading) 
* Environment: development 
* Debug mode: on 
* Restarting with stat 
False 
False
```

and I get the FileNotFoundError

Comment: Pretty unclear question… Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve].

Comment: "I still get: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '..\\..\\models\\lr_scaler.pkl'" Well, the error is pretty explicit: it's telling you that the file isn't at that location. So - why do you expect it to be at that location? You're using a relative path - where do you expect it to be relative *to*? Did you **test** that expectation? What happened when you did? If it *does* match, what happened when you tried to check the corresponding folder? Does it actually contain the `.pkl` file in question?

Comment: There is no way that anyone else can tell you *why* the file isn't in a particular place, because we don't have your file system, nor do we have... whatever it was that was supposed to *put* the file there.

Comment: If you were able to find the file using your operating system, what happens if you copy the file to a different path and try to open it from that path?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel That's quite unfriendly. OP showed how `os.path.getsize()` reports the correct size of the file, so we know the file exists on the file system. So let's help OP figure out why `os.path.getsize()` and `pickle.load()` see things differently.

Comment: @Remssett_HP That being said, I still have to ask the stupid question: you show that `os.path.getsize()` sees `lr_model.pkl`, but can you also use it to see `lr_scaler.pkl`? My attempts to reproduce your problem didn't work - my similar code with a pickle file I just created work just fine.

Comment: "So let's help OP figure out why os.path.getsize() and pickle.load() see things differently." The error is apparently being reported by `open`, not by `pickle.load`. I'm talking through how to debug the apparent issue with the file system. Nothing unfriendly about that.

Comment: @joanis yeah, I used one path as an example but both of them return the desired path and size, but now I noticed someting else. if I check the paths with print(os.path.exists(model_filepath)), this happens:
True
True
 * Serving Flask app "machine_learning_api" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: development
 * Debug mode: on
 * Restarting with stat
False
False

 - and I get the FileNotFoundError

Comment: I would guess, then, that when the "Restarting" is happening, your working directory be changed, or something like that. Something is changing in the context. Maybe add a line printing `os.getcwd()` in there? If the context might change like that, you might have to provide an absolute path to the model dir.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel yes, the files exist and I chacked them on the API with print(os.path.getsize(scaler_filepath)). but it seems like the paths are changed after the API restarts

Comment: @KarlKnechtel OK, thanks for clarifying. I'm glad I just misunderstood your intentions.

Comment: "it seems like the paths are changed after the API restarts " I don't understand what this means. Are you saying that you saw the path debugging work correctly one time that you ran the program, and the unpickling fail a separate time? Did you try checking what the current working directory was each time? Did you try checking the expected file location *at the time that a failure occurred*?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I edited the question with the print(os.path.exists(model_filepath)) test to show what I mean.

Comment: Okay, *that's* a problem that can be investigated. The next step is to debug where in the restarting process the problem occurs. You might also check whether the current working directory gets changed.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel yeah, turns out if I check with print(os.getcwd()), the directory changes.
the first time it runs it's C:\python\projects\ml-model\src\models - 
and the second time it's C:\python\projects\ml-model - if I change it to work on the second path it breaks on the first run, how can I fix this?

Comment: At this point I think it may be better if you ask a new question, armed with this knowledge.

Comment: not sure what causes that, but I just fixed it by saving the API script on the ml-model folder and setting the model_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(),'models'), and now it works. thanks for the help figuring it out.

Answer (score 0):

tested with

```
print(os.getcwd())
print(os.path.exists(model_filepath))
print(os.path.exists(scaler_filepath))
```

and turns out the working directory is being changed so it broke the relative paths when the API restarted.

```
C:\python\projects\ml-model\src\models
True
True
 * Serving Flask app "machine_learning_api" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: development
 * Debug mode: on
 * Restarting with stat
C:\python\projects\ml-model
False
False
```

saving the API script on the ml-model folder and setting

```
model_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(),'models')
```

fixed it.